# ActiveMQ Admin Console Topic Subscribers Metrics

Tags: activemq-classic

What's the difference between Pending Queue Size, Dispatched Queue Size,   Dispatched Counter, Enqueue Counter, Dequeue Counter in ActiveMQ Admin Console? How to detect which consumer is slow?

Answer (score 1):

- Enqueue Count: Number of messages sent to the destination
- Dequeue Count: Number of messages that have permanently been removed from the destination
- Dispatch Count: Number of messages that have been sent to a consumer
  (this may be higher than total enqueue count if consumers reject
  messages and the broker has to redeliver messages)
- Queue Size: Number of messages currently in the queue (aka Enqueue Count minus
  Dequeue Count)